# Segregation: group distance

Tags: geometry

Suppose there are two groups of people: group A and group B. The groups are of equal size.
All individuals have a position in the plane (a map). It is possible for 2 or more (or all) individuals to be in the same spot.
Distance is straight line distance.

My question:
*Is it possible for the average distance (over all individuals from the two groups) to individuals from the other group to be smaller than the average distance (again over all individuals from the two groups) to members of their own group?*

Or, formulated differently: is it possible that, on average, individuals have to walk less far to meet the average individual from the other group than to meet the average individual from their own group?

Or: can $\overline{d_O} < \overline{d_S}$? $\overline{d_O}$ then denotes the average distance to dissimilar individuals and $\overline{d_S}$ denotes the average distance to similar individuals.

Important: when calculating averages, the distance to oneself is taken into account as well. The distance from an individual to itself is zero. So if there would be only 1 group, consisting of 2 individuals, the average distance to similar individuals would be the distance between these 2 individuals, divided by 2.

I think the answer to my question is no. But I struggle to prove it in general.

Some remarks:

- With 2 groups that have different sizes, the answer is yes. Easy example: a square with 4 members from group A at each corner and 1 member from group B in the middle. The average distance from dissimilar individuals will be smaller than the average distance to similar individuals.
- When all individuals are paired with someone from the other group (i.e. at each location, there is an equal number of group A and group B people), the two average distances will be the same. Moving any individual to any other location on the map will always increase $\overline{d_O}$ relative to $\overline{d_S}$. Thus, this situation is a local optimum, but I would like to show it is a global optimum.

Looking forward to your suggestions... Thanks